# How to select centroids within buffer range?

Tags: qgis, buffer, centroids

I want to select the red circled centroids. These centroids must be within the blue buffer.

[image: Centroid I want to select.]

Comment: Seems like you meant to include an image in your question.

Comment: Image added, made a mistake. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Select by location` tool. Go to the `Vector` menu, then `Research / Select by location`. The first layer is the point layer, the second one is the polygon.

[image]

Comment: This is a good suggestion as well, and probably the easier route to go if you're using QGIS 3.0. I believe the Spatial Query tool has been removed in that release. Makes sense-- Spatial Query and Select by Location are pretty much identical.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Spatial Query tool under the Vector menu to select the centroids that fall within your buffer polygons. Select the centroids as the Source Features, the buffer layer as the Reference Feature, and use the dropdown to select "within" for the selection type.

[image]

Comment: The Spatial Query tool must first be activated from the plugin menu.

Comment: Certainly worth checking if you don't see the option. But I don't think I've ever had an install that didn't have it activated by default.